# ListView in fragment not scrolling when main activity has scrollview

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a mainactivity xml which contains scrollview containing 2 linear layouts.
First layout have all buttons and second layout is used as fragment which i populate based on click of a button.(See mainactivity.xml)

On click of a button (say btn_11), i populate listview attached to it(btn_11.xml attached).

My problem is my listview is not scrolling.

Please assist.

mainactivity.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        style="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8cb990"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="btn_11"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="btn_12"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="btn_13"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="btn_14"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="btn_15"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_16"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="btn_1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="btn_1"
               android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_18"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="btn_18"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/myfragment"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.38"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

btn_11.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_11data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="true"
        android:text="btn_11data" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/id_mylistView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ListView doesn't scroll because ScrollView catchs every scroll event. I think you should override ScrollView and methods which catch scroll events, and you should check if scroll bounds inside your ListView and don't process these events in your extended ScrollView..